# Remove function on specific window size

Tags: jquery

I want to remove this function when my screen resize but on a specific window size. How can I make that using jquery? Thanks in advance!

```
function reviewSameHeight() {
 var reviewSummaryHeight = $('.review-details').outerHeight(true);
 $(".order-summary").height(reviewSummaryHeight);
}
```

Comment: you can use the `resize` event here.
https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing the event handlers pointing to that function, it would be simpler just to check the window size within the function itself and then act appropriately. For example:

```
function reviewSameHeight() {
    var $win = $(window);
    if ($win.width() > 800 && $win.height() > 600) {
        var reviewSummaryHeight = $('.review-details').outerHeight(true);
        $(".order-summary").height(reviewSummaryHeight);
    }
}
```